# Showing XML responses using variables

Tags: php, xml

Can you help me? I'm facing a strange problem when parsing my XML.

Here is my PHP script:

```
$xml = "https://pastebin.com/raw/30QHhFSr";
$response = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($xml)) or die('error');

$auto = "ENDS->E0->ENDERECO";

echo $response->$auto; //output: nothing
echo $response->ENDS->E0->ENDERECO; //output: SAO SEVERINO //works
```

Why `$response->$auto;` is not working?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot automatically do what you want, you would have to break down `$auto` and do it level by level.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: strange problem? no, its just your arrow notation is actually a string literal, that's why  there's no output

Comment: you cant do with string variable pass as object key to get value so have to follow process  :  [ $response->ENDS->E0->ENDERECO ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What getting is correct since your arrow notation is actually a string literal, which in itself doesn't do anything when you do:

```
$auto = "ENDS->E0->ENDERECO";

echo $response->$auto;
echo $response->{"ENDS->E0->ENDERECO"}; // it doesn't really exist
```

The alternative is you can process the string and break it down using `explode`, and use array reduce.

Here's the idea:

```
$xml = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/30QHhFSr';
$response = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($xml)) or die('error');
$auto = 'ENDS->E0->ENDERECO';
echo array_reduce(explode('->', $auto), function ($o, $p) { 
    return $o->$p; 
}, $response);
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle by the way https://www.tehplayground.com/zr2LIWX0Ce50PKFz

Answer (score 0):

> **->**, is used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property
>
> **[SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)** - Represents an element in an XML document.

`$response` is an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`, You need to define like this

```
$level1 = "ENDS";
$level2 = "E0";
$level3 = "ENDERECO";
```

Now you can retrieve the value using

```
$response->$level1->$level2->$level3;
```